# How to run a function that was created in the class? Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a project in Android Studio. I faced a problem in that I don't know how to call a function that was created in the class. I want to call test() in the same file so it will add some values to my FireBase DB but when I run the program I get the following Errors.
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE2to.png)

**Or can you suggest to me how I can run my function to check if it adds something to my Firestore? Even if I don't have the other code to successfully run the whole application**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

 class MyDataBase {

    lateinit var db: DocumentReference

    var isStudent = true

    fun initializeDbRef() {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("Users")

    }

    fun writeNewUser(email: String, pass: String) {

        val items = HashMap<String, Any>()
        items.put("Password", pass)
        db.collection("Students").document("wIPzm1J5zZtVPksa1J8z").set(items)
    }

     fun test(name: String, email: String) {
         val database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
         val myRef = database.collection("Users")

         val newUser = hashMapOf(
             "name" to name,
             "email" to email
         )

         myRef.add(newUser)

     }
 }

fun main() {
    val myObject = MyDataBase()
    val result = myObject.test("maks", "email.com")
}
```

I have tried to add a main function and to run the application

```
fun main() {
    val myObject = MyDataBase()
    val result = myObject.test("maks", "email.com")
}
```

Comment: This probably needs to be done using Android unit testing, so you can have a stand-in for the main thread Looper. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals

Comment: So you basically want to know if you're using this line `db.collection("Students").document("wIPzm1J5zZtVPksa1J8z").set(items)` is the user actually added or not in the database? If this what you need, then please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo No, I am trying to do it in the different function test(). But it is almost the same. so yeah I want to know if user actually added to my data base.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following line of code:

```
db.collection("Students").document("wIPzm1J5zZtVPksa1J8z").set(items)
```

It means that you're trying to add a document to Firestore. However, there is nothing that indicates if the operation succeeds or fails. To know that, you have to attach a [success listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnSuccessListener) to see when the operation is successful and a [failure listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnFailureListener) to see when the operation fails with an Exception. So in code that would be:

```
db.collection("Students").document("wIPzm1J5zZtVPksa1J8z").set(items)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "You have added the document successfully.")
    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed with: ${e.message}")
    }
```